# Order of execution of recorded and asserted methods in coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new to coded UI. When we record an action and generate code for it, a recorded method is generated. When we add assertions to that action, asserted methods are generated. Both the recorded and asserted methods are called in CodedUITestMethod().
Is there any order of execution for recorded and asserted methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods recorded for actions and methods recorded for assertions are simply methods in either C# or VB. These methods are called from the test method (with default name `CodedUITest1.cs`) and so their execution order is the same as the order of their calls.

When you create a new Coded UI test a popup window asks whether you want to record a test, or to convert an action recording or to cancel. If you select the default and choose to record a test then the methods are generated and calls of those methods are added into the test method. If you record a sequence with a mix of action methods and assertion methods then the calls will be generated in the order the are recorded.

Having recorded a number of methods you can right click where a statement is allowed within the `CodedUITest1.cs` file and select the record and generate option. That will let you record one or more new action and/or assertion methods and the calls will be inserted where you right-clicked.

If you cancel the popup you can record action and assertion methods and save them into other UI Map files - search for details of multiple UI Map files for more detail. When recording into multiple UI Map files you will need to add the calls yourself into the test method.